# Python: iterate over dict containing list vals

Tags: python, loops

I have a dict of unknown length, and with strings as keys and lists as vals:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
vars = OrderedDict(( ('first', [0,1,2,3]),
                     ('second', [4,5]),
                     ('third', [6,7,8]),
                  ))
```

I need to iterate over each list in a nested way. if I knew the dict length, I could do so easily:

```
for v1 in vars['first']:
    for v2 in vars['second']:
        for v3 in vars['third']:
            do_something(v1,v2,v3)
```

But because len(vars) is not known, I don't know how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to run `do_something` with all permutations of all values from all lists…? So, with a longer dict you'd run `do_something(v1, v2, v3, v4)` *a^b^c^d* times…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`, which gives you all combinations of the values in the lists.

```py
import itertools

for vals in itertools.product(*vars.values()):
    do_something(*vals)
```